# Adding a DOT (.) to Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex

I'm looking to add a (`.`) to the allowed characters in my function below:

```
$(id).bind('keypress', function(event) {
    var regex = new RegExp("[()a-zA-Z0-9 ?,/-]");
    var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
    if (!regex.test(key)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

However, every time I add it it comes up with the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /[()a-zA-Z0-9
>   ?,/-.]/: Range out of order in character class

I've tried adding just (`.`) & also tried adding it with (`\.`) but still the same error.

Please can you assist to where I need to add this (`.`) ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that `-` should either be at the beginning or at the end of character class or has to be escaped by a backslash `\`, since it indicates *range* as in `a-z`

```
/[()a-zA-Z0-9 ?,/.-]/
```

Also, if dynamic regex is required, just use the regex literal as in above, if not you'd have to remove the delimiters `/ /` and use the actual regex `[()a-zA-Z0-9 ?,/.-]` as a `String` which can be used in `RegExp` constructor.

Comment: Thanks, This works perfect and thanks for the explanation. Will mark as answer once the time limit has expired.

Comment: @Josh90 ah! Glad to have helped :)